# How to make sequence jump from 100 to 150

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-sequence

How to fire sequence to jump from 100 to 150 and followed by 152,153 and so on . .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Also please not that we are not magicians and we are not in your mind, we can not guess what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sequence `seq1` is now at 100 and you want it to go to 150 you can:

- Change its increment to 50.
- Use it once.
- Change its increment back to 1.

In SQL terms:

```
alter sequence seq1 increment by 50;
select seq1.nextval from dual;
alter sequence seq1 increment by 1;
```